# how to optimize by grouping multiple web service calls into one. design pattern c#

Tags: class, oop, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

here is the downnload link
https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=c565323a2a3927de&page=self&resid=C565323A2A3927DE!234&parid=C565323A2A3927DE!119&authkey=!Av1VEdfY3hmpl14&Bpub=SDX.SkyDrive&Bsrc=Share

So i have a domain model like this.

```
public enum ItemType
{
    TypeA,
    TypeB
}    

public class Item
{
    public int ID;
    public ItemType Type;
    public ItemServiceFactory Factory = new ItemServiceFactory();

    public IItemService ItemService { get; set; } 

    public Item(ItemType type )
    {
        ItemService = Factory.GetItemService(type);
        Type = type;
    }

    public ItemValue GetValue()
    {
        return ItemService.GetValue(this);
    }

}

public interface IItemService
{
    ItemValue GetValue(Item item);
}

public class ItemServiceA : IItemService
{
    private readonly WebServiceA _webServiceA = new WebServiceA();

    public ItemValue GetValue(Item item)
    {
        return new ItemValue(_webServiceA.GetValuesA(new List<int> { item.ID }).FirstOrDefault());
    }
}

public class ItemServiceB : IItemService
{
    private readonly WebServiceB _webServiceB = new WebServiceB();

    public ItemValue GetValue(Item item)
    {
        return new ItemValue(_webServiceB.GetValuesB(new List<int> { item.ID }).FirstOrDefault());
    }
}

public class ItemServiceFactory
{
    public IItemService GetItemService(ItemType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case ItemType.TypeA: return new ItemServiceA();
            case ItemType.TypeB: return new ItemServiceB();

            default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }
}

public class ItemValue
{
    public int Value;

    public ItemValue(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}

public class WebServiceB
{
    public IEnumerable<int> GetValuesB(IEnumerable<int> idList)
    {//call web service. dummy here.
        return idList.Select(x => x + 100);
    }
}

public class WebServiceA
{
    public IEnumerable<int> GetValuesA(IEnumerable<int> idList)
    {//call web service. dummy here.
        return idList.Select(x => x - 100);
    }
}



var tooManyItems = new List<Item>
    {
        new Item(ItemType.TypeA),
        new Item(ItemType.TypeA),
        new Item(ItemType.TypeA),
        new Item(ItemType.TypeA),
        new Item(ItemType.TypeA),
        new Item(ItemType.TypeA),
        new Item(ItemType.TypeA),
        new Item(ItemType.TypeA),

        new Item(ItemType.TypeB),
        new Item(ItemType.TypeB),
        new Item(ItemType.TypeB),
        new Item(ItemType.TypeB),
        new Item(ItemType.TypeB),
        new Item(ItemType.TypeB),
        new Item(ItemType.TypeB),
        new Item(ItemType.TypeB)
    };

    Console.WriteLine(tooManyItems.Select(x => x.GetValue().Value));//or whatever.
```

now i am following the DDD (domain driven design) and i really want to keep the **Item** class to know how to get it's value. In the current model, when the Item class is initialized, it sets the **ItemServiceA/ItemServiceB** based the **Itemtype**. Now when the ItemObj.GetValue() is called, Item class 'Knows' what service it has to use and subsequently in this code, what web service to call.

Note: Although the WebService supports the call of a list of items, in the current model, it is always passed as one item list only.(for every Item object's GetValue())

now the problem in the current code is that if i have a long list of Items and i want the values of all items, and they are from some Web Service, this is very inefficient and slow.

Question: In this design, i want to keep the Item to know how to get its value and also, want to group the calls of multiple items into two different calls to WebServiceA and WebServiceB. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: people, could you please stop downvoting a question while it is still  being edited. Everyone is mature enough to know that we need to save drafts to save work when u have connection problems and stuff.

Comment: No, you're not supposed to save drafts online. Save drafts on your own computer.

Comment: I understand. i was looking for saving it as draft..could't find it. is there even a feature like this in here? I have done this many times in msdn though. This is more like the downvote of a user. StackOverflow should add more features like why a downvote. why should the question and hence the community suffer.

Comment: Downvotes are explained in comments. I downvoted, and didn't care to explain why, because it looked obvious to me. There was no question at all, no explanation, only a wall of code. Questions are written in Markdown, which is plain text. Just use a text editor and save drafts offline if you want to have drafts. I don't see any need for drafts, since you can view the result of the formatting in real-time while typing the question.

Comment: sure. will take care. Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify what the problem is? performance?

Comment: One of the goals of DDD is persistence ignorance and having the Item class "know" how to get its value would fail in that respect.

Comment: mrhobo, yes. issue is of performance.

Comment: Item is persistence ignorant. it only depends on the abstraction, not the actualy service type which is injected into it. so it is not failing DDD.

Comment: the factory here is just for the ease of reading of code. ideally i would only have that IItemService (which would be a domain servcie),  the instance of which would be injected  from outside based on some configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, since no-one has answered the question, i am going to post my own solution for this.
what i did was based on a multithreaded approach. There will be a new worker thread  for each Item::GetValue call. I have crated a new class, called BatchItemService, whose job is to listen to thse calls and make its own call, after grouping based on its logic and when the call is finished, notify the waiting threads for it to run to completion. I'll have to put a strict timeout policy on this to ensure that the threads count come back to normal no matter what.

here is the code

```
    private static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Item, ItemValue>> GetResultsAsync(IEnumerable<Item> tooManyItems)
{
    var returnResult = new List<KeyValuePair<Item, ItemValue>>();
    var threads = new List<Thread>();

    foreach (var thread in tooManyItems.Select(item => new Thread(() => returnResult.Add(new KeyValuePair<Item, ItemValue>(item, item.GetItemValue())))))
    {
        threads.Add(thread);
        thread.Start();
    }
    foreach (var thread in threads)
        thread.Join();

    return returnResult;
}


public class ItemServiceFactory
{
    private static BatchItemService _batchItemService;

    public IItemService GetItemService(ItemType type)
    {
        return _batchItemService ?? (_batchItemService = new BatchItemService());
    }
}



public class BatchItemService : IItemService
{
    private static readonly List<Item> ItemsToCall = new List<Item>();
    private static readonly List<KeyValuePair<Item, ItemValue>> ItemsCalled = new List<KeyValuePair<Item, ItemValue>>();
    private static readonly object LockAll = new object();
    private bool _defer;



    private readonly System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(50);

    public BatchItemService()
    {
        _timer.Enabled = true;
        _timer.Elapsed += MakeConsolidatedWebServiceCall;
    }

    private void MakeConsolidatedWebServiceCall(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_defer)
        {
            return;
        }

        _defer = true;

        lock (LockAll)
        {
            if (ItemsToCall.Count != 0)
            {

                var ItemAItemsToCall = new List<Item>();
                var ItemBItemsToCall = new List<Item>();


                ItemAItemsToCall.AddRange(ItemsToCall.Where(x => x.Type == ItemType.ItemA));

                if (ItemAItemsToCall.Any())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("calling ItemAWebService");
                    var ItemAMeaureResults =
                        (new ItemAWebService()).GetItemAResults(ItemAItemsToCall.Select(x => x.ID));
                    ItemsCalled.AddRange(ItemAMeaureResults.Zip(ItemAItemsToCall,
                                                                  (first, second) =>
                                                                  new KeyValuePair<Item, ItemValue>(second,
                                                                                                           new ItemValue
                                                                                                               (first))));
                }

                ItemBItemsToCall.AddRange(ItemsToCall.Where(x => x.Type == ItemType.ItemB));

                if (ItemBItemsToCall.Any())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("calling ItemBWebService");
                    var ItemBItemValues = (new ItemBWebService()).GetItemBResults(ItemBItemsToCall.Select(x => x.ID));
                    ItemsCalled.AddRange(ItemBItemValues.Zip(ItemBItemsToCall,
                                                                  (first, second) =>
                                                                  new KeyValuePair<Item, ItemValue>(second,
                                                                                                           new ItemValue
                                                                                                               (first))));

                }

                foreach (var Item in ItemAItemsToCall.Concat(ItemBItemsToCall))
                {
                    ItemsToCall.Remove(Item);
                }
            }


            Monitor.PulseAll(LockAll);
            _defer = false;
        }
    }

    public ItemValue GetItemValue(Item Item)
    {
        ItemValue returnVal;

        lock (LockAll)
        {
            ItemsToCall.Add(Item);
        }

        lock (LockAll)
        {
            Monitor.Wait(LockAll);
            returnVal = ItemsCalled.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key.ID.Equals(Item.ID)).Value;
            if (returnVal == null)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException(" value cannot be null. sync issue ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("received result for Item ID:" + returnVal.Value);
            ItemsCalled.Remove(ItemsCalled.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key.ID.Equals(Item.ID)));
        }

        return returnVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I recommend against using the code you've written here because you're manually creating threads and calling Thread.Join to wait until your threads have stopped.  Manually creating threads is much more expensive than using the ThreadPool. Before I offer a code example of how to accomplish what you're after, what version of .NET are you using?

Comment: what you're saying is right. I initially tried to use a thread pool. but the problem with this approach is that the function that i intend to call, should be called from all objects almost instantaneously. if i use a thread pool, only the active threads call that function and wait, while the rest is not even started yet. so in that case, i was not able to do any optmization. the whole reason i am trying different things is to combine multiple http calls into one single call, grouping as many calls as possible. I am  using 4.0 and not to mention ASP.NET, NOT WinForms.

Comment: additionaly, what i believe is that creating threds is not bad by itelf, but not managing their lifetime is. if i go for a aggressive srategy, the number of threds quicly go high and is supposed to come back quickly down also.

Comment: another reason i am thinking in these terms is the plug-and-play concept. i can just plug those requred classes with whatever functinality we need, wihthout disturbing the domain. its just a matter of one liners in Registries in structuremap.

Comment: here is the download link  "https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=c565323a2a3927de&page=self&resid=C565323A2A3927DE!234&parid=C565323A2A3927DE!119&authkey=!Av1VEdfY3hmpl14&Bpub=SDX.SkyDrive&Bsrc=Share"

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're having issues is because you've assigned class responsibilities improperly. Specifically, the `Item` class has too many responsibilities - it contains a factory and a service in addition to its own state. The problem you're running into with the web service is one of the most common pitfalls of distributed computing which is the assumption that you can call network bound code in the same way as you would in-process code. To address these issues, do the following:

1) Make web service calls explicit in the model. Your web service classes are already designed to return multiple values, so you should have your abstraction (interface) has the same signature.

2) Shift the responsibility of calling the service away from the `Item` class. This will also allow you to get rid of the factory which in this instance I would call the service locator anti-patter. Sometimes it is acceptable, but not in this case.

3) Restructure the web service abstraction such that it can return values for multiple items of a specified item, not just a single item type. This way, you can call it for multiple items at a time and have the abstraction worry about which actual web service to call.

Answer (score 0):

I do understand what you're trying to do: you have a web service that accepts a list of items and returns a list of values for those items. But your domain is modeled in such a way that your client code can only request one item/value at a time.  Since I don't know what your application does or why you architected it that way, I cannot make any judgments on this.

Still though, spinning up a new thread to handle this is a bit more expensive than using the thread pool, and it isn't really necessary.  I'd change your `GetResultsAsync` method to look like this:

```cs
private static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Item, ItemResult>> GetResultsAsync(IEnumerable<Item> tooManyItems) {
    var returnResult = new List<KeyValuePair<Item, ItemResult>>();
    Parallel.ForEach(tooManyItems, item => returnResult.Add(new KeyValuePair<Item, ItemResult>(item, item.GetItemResult())));
    return returnResult;
}
```

This implementation uses the thread pool and accomplishes what you're after.